# Program ends with exit code 0 immediately - but it shouldn't get there without input

Tags: c

Build succeeds. If I open the output window, it reads:

> Program ended with exit code: 0

But my program is such that this shouldn't be possible, without first having taken user input, done some stuff, and taken another user input, all in `int main()`.

The first thing `int main()` does is loop through taking input for `p`, until the input is one (of two) desired options. So there's no way it should be able to exit immediately - it initialises `p=0` and doesn't exit a `while` loop until `p` is 1 or 2.

Is there some hidden error that has allowed the build to succeed without it actually.. succeeding?

```
int main(){
    //vars
    while (TRUE){
        //play computer or human?
        while (!(p == 1 || p == 2)) {
            printf("Single player or two player? (1/2): ");
            scanf("%d", &p);
        }

        if (p==1) {
            //play computer
        }

        else {
            //snip
        }

        printf("%s won the game! Play again?", winner);
        scanf("%s", playagain);
        if (strncmp(playagain,"no",2)==0){
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where's the code? Can we see it?

Comment: It's a bit long, I thought what I said would be sufficient. I'll add.

Comment: Please put back in enough of your code to make this a small, self-contained, compilable example (SSCCE) program that demonstrates the problem. That'll let us help you without guesswork and you'll probably realize what the problem is yourself in the course of coming up with the SSCCE.

Comment: Just run it with a debugger to satisfy yourself that your assumptions are correct.

Comment: The question was originally tagged with xCode as well. Are you running this in main.m in xCode or as an added c file in an xCode project or pure C (editor + gcc)?

Comment: You should change your while loop to do..while loop.

Comment: @Spectravideo328 it's all in main.c in an xcode project. I didn't remove the tag, presumably someone knows it's not an xcode issue and removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print out what uppercase `TRUE` is defined as. I have seen some ambitious but inexperienced folks do weird things with it. You might not even be getting into your main `while` loop.

```
printf("TRUE is %d\n",TRUE);
```

If this is nonzero, then your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: TRUE is `typedef enum bool {TRUE, FALSE} bool;`. Is that the issue.. it's not actually a real boolean, so it doesn't evaluate to 1 for the `while`...

I think by the time I'd gotten to the loop, I'd forgotten TRUE was of my own definition. I have more experience in Python, where boolean type is included, and while true makes perfect sense.

Comment: `while (TRUE)` can make sense in C as well - as  long as `TRUE` has a reasonable value (where reasonable means it has the value 1). However, I think that most C programmers either use the boolean types from `stdbool.h` (a C99 addition) or just use 0 or 1.  I think that today I'd avoid creating my own type named `bool` since it will run afoul of code that uses `stdbool.h` or if/when it's used in a C++ context.  Maybe just use `enum {FALSE,TRUE};`